# Copy Data and Compare Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, connection, compare

Not very sure if this is possible in its entirety but i know it most probably is separately. I have a shared macro-enabled document on our network and want to be able to see what has been updated.  Firstly, a few things to point out;

1. The worksheet in question (combined sheet) has a macro where it picks the data/range from 10 other worksheets (which are placed from connections) and displays into the combined sheet. The reason for this is because the 10 other worksheets are updated by other users/teams. This combined sheet of course just displays all data in one.
2. What we want to add now is something that will let as know what the most recent entries are. I have seen some code that will place a time stamp on the next column of the field that has been update & This doesn't work for us.
3. Someone mentioned pulling that Data from combined sheet (as live) to a new workbook. having another sheet in this workbook as last updated sheet and then another worksheet that does a compare & highlights the difference.

I understand that this is an unusual request and have no idea what method (trying to be efficient) to take & execute this request.

Any advise/tips welcomed.

This is a snippet of the code already in place;

```
`Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Sheets("Business Development").Range("A2:T50").Copy
Sheets("Combined").Activate
Range("A4:T50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Compliance").Range("A2:T50").Copy
Sheets("Combined").Activate
Range("A52:T101").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub`
```

Comment: "I have seen some code that will place a time stamp on the next column of the field that has been update & This doesn't work for us." Care to elaborate on why?

Comment: Because the individual sheets are connections. i would have to place this timestamp in the origin doc of each individual sheet. will changing this doc to a macro-enabled doc (by adding the code) not change the connection?

Comment: "I have a shared macro-enabled document on our network"  Isn't it already a macro-enabled doc?  And you can do basically anything with a macro.  Making a summary sheet of what changed and sorting it by most recent would be pretty easy for a simple "log" style table.

Comment: I guess as default, the workbook filetype would just be .xls but as its macro enabled it changes to .xlsm

with the combined sheet, i already have a macro in place and a button where i click the button and it runs the macro pulling the data from the other 10 sheets.  Not sure how to go about showing updates? As i mentioned, the other 10 sheets are connections so not sure what to do as that macro at the moment only pulls the data in.

Comment: Please edit your OP and put your code there. As you can see, it's very difficult to read in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @FreeMan I have now edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do :

1- Add a "hash" function in your VBA module, see [Create a hash value](https://superuser.com/questions/550592/is-there-an-excel-function-to-create-a-hash-value#answer-550605)
.

2- In the next column of the data (let's say column E) you add this function : `=base64sha1(CONCATENATE(A10;B10;C10;D10))`.
This will give you a hash code based on your data in columns A, B, C, D : each time a value change, the hash code changes.

3- In your update macro, before doing your update, make a copy of column E in column F.

4- The last thing is to setup a Conditional Formatting that checks if value in column E is different form value in column F.

NB: If you set the header of your column E to `Now()` and, in step `3-`, you insert a new column before column F (rather than overwrite previous hash codes), you will have all information to know which row was changed and when.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A hash code doesn't guarantee uniqueness, so you can't use it as a unique identifier.

Comment: You're right! It's not a unique identifier and I will edit my answer. But the hash code suits for his problem.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this and confirm.

Comment: @Jibato am i to just copy the code in this link you have provided and this will work?

Comment: Yes, just copy both functions in a VBA module (not in the workbook or a sheet).

Comment: Thanks @Jibato . I can't seem to get it working, after placing in the module, trying to run, its asking for me to give it a name etc as if it cant see the code even though it has been saved.  Also, is this code going to give me a timestamp or just hashed code, please help me understand what this code does in this situation? Regards.

Comment: If you put BASE64SHA1 and EncodeBase64 functions in a module inside your Modules folder of the VBAProject, you should be able to use BASE64SHA1 function in the sheet. You should even have autocompletion when you begin to type =BASE in a cell. Can you confirm you don't have autocompletion for this function ?

Comment: The code will give you a hash code. If this hash code change it means at least one of your cell data in A10, B10, C10 or D10 changed.

Comment: Don't run this function inside VBA Editor but use it in your worksheet.

Comment: Thanks, this works; what can i do with this hashed code now? @Jibato

Comment: Do you just need to highlight last updated rows or you need the last change date for each row ?

Comment: I need the last date change for each row.  That could then allow me to add a filter/sort by date @Jibato

Comment: Let's say your data are in Columns A to C, the hash code in E. In your combined sheet, modify the macro that pull the data : before pulling new data, insert a column after E (Range("F1").EntireColumn.Insert), copy/paste column E values (not formulas) in F, and store date/time value in your hash code header (Range("E1" = Now).

Comment: And finally, after you updated your data you create a loop that check, for each row if Range("Ex") is different from Range("Fx"). If it is, you copy Range("E1") (=date/time)) in Range("Dx). So you will have in column D the last change dates.